# App for long audio?

Tags: android, audio, music, media-player

I'm listening to a 22 hour audio book in a single file on my Android. I've tried 3 music apps so far and it's almost impossible to rewind in all of them.

I want to be able to change the current play time more accurately. Even having fast forward and rewind buttons would help.

Any music apps which would be good for this use case?

Comment: Must the app be free, or how much would you be willing to pay? Also, while waiting for answers, be welcome to check my list of apps for [FolderPlay & AudioBooks](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay).

Comment: Are you completely opposed to simply splitting the file into shorter pieces?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy only because it would be very time consuming and I don't always know that I will even finish an audio book when I start reading.